# C++ custom exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, cuda

I have run into broken compiler, which does not allow exceptions to inherit from `std::exception` (nvcc 3.0).

so had to create workaround:

```
struct exception {
    explicit exception(const char* message) {
        what_ = message;
    }
    virtual const char *what() const throw() { return what_; }
    operator std::exception() const {
        return std::runtime_error(what_);
    }
private:
    const char* what_;
};

struct configuration_error : exception {
    configuration_error(const char* message)
        : exception(message) {}
};
```

is there something I am going to lose by not inheriting from exception, instead providing cast?  is what necessary in the above case?

thank you

Comment: Why doesn't it let you inherit from it? (Errors?) Perhaps we can hack around it and enable inheritance, or is it strictly just a "simply can't" thing?

Comment: In what way does it not allow deriving from `std::exception`? BTW, it is probably better to inherit from one of the `<stdexcept>` types (`std::exception` doesn't even have a useful constructor). - Your workaround also seems to suffer from a very questionable way of storing the string - are you sure that the pointer might not become invalid in case of a local string?

Comment: @GMan I get `external call to exception ` error.  Which does not make any sense because that is device function specific error.  This only affects when you try to initialize complex object in constructor.  I am pretty sure this is compiler bug, previous compiler (nvcc 2.x)had no problem

Comment: @UncleBens I know, unfortunately the same problem appears when using string or inheriting from anything in stdexcept.

Comment: You should upgrade to 3.1. In its defence, CUDA C is a subset of C++ and additional C++ features are being added all the time. Having said that, the code in question is being passed through to the host compiler so it should work.

Answer (score 2):

`catch (std::exception)` will not catch your exception, and you cannot `dynamic_cast` your exception to `std::exception` either.  If your program never does either of those things, you're fine.

Personally I would not use a compiler this broken, though.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to CUDA 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create an instance of something derived from std::exception on the device, it won't work because the std::exception constructor would need to be called, and that is not a device function.

Throwing and catching your own type is probably the solution. Since it probably will never make it back to host code, though (C++ doesn't really handle throwing multiple exceptions in parallel), compatibility with std::exception shouldn't be too much of an issue.